# Can you play fuel cards without moving

Tags: dead-of-winter

Is it possible to play a fuel card without moving?

Fuel card: "WASTE PILE: Play this card when moving a survivor you control..."

Rule book: "Play a card: as many times as he likes during his turn, a player may play a card from his hand. To play a card, place it on top of the waste pile."

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no mention of any exception, and the wording doesn't specify the option such as by saying "you **may** move a survivor etc", so it sounds like the answer to your question is no, you may not opt to play it without moving.